# css style overrides?

Tags: css, design, styles

I was able to get my custom font to my `custom theme`.

I made a style (CSS file) to use it, but the text-transform and letter-spacing attributes are being inherited from another style sheet?

What do I need to do to make sure that my `ss_logo` style always wins?

Please forgive my ignorance. I haven't done any web-type development for over 10 years.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Include `steamspeed_logo.css` after `styles.css` at head section in HTML and user css selector like this: `.parallax-banners-wrapper .text-banner .banner-content h2.ss_logo` instead of `.ss_logo`.

Answer (score 1):

```
.ss_logo {
  text-transform: none !important;
  letter-spacing: 0 !important;
}
```

likely the above would do what you are after. Now, to give a better answer, we'd need to see the html and ideally, have the page in our browser.. but hopefully the above is working for you.